# why is this looping when I give 'y' as input but running perfectly fine when I give an 'n'

Tags: c++

The issue is somewhere in main. Will someone please help me. I have been working on this for hours, and it will not stop looping. I cannot think of any ethical reason why this code would be looping. The reason I have this giant paragraph here is because stackOverflow would not let me publish the question without more details. What happens is it runs fine if I press 'n' but it loops endlessly asking for filing status if I press 'y'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h> 
using namespace std;

void CalculateTaxAmount(char status, double amount){
   int taxRate = 0;
   int subAmount = 0;
   int addAmount = 0;
   switch (status){
      case 's':
         {
            if (amount < 864){taxRate = 0; subAmount = 0; addAmount = 0;}
            else
               if (amount < 2589){taxRate = 1; subAmount = 863; addAmount = 25;}
               else
                  if (amount < 4313){taxRate = 2; subAmount = 2588; addAmount = 85;}
                  else {taxRate = 3; subAmount = 4313; addAmount = 181;}
         }
         //end single
         break;
      case 'm':
         {
            if (amount < 1727){taxRate = 0; subAmount = 0; addAmount = 0;}
            else
               if (amount < 5177){taxRate = 1; subAmount = 1726; addAmount = 40;}
               else
                  if (amount < 8626){taxRate = 2; subAmount = 5176; addAmount = 175;}
                  else {taxRate = 3; subAmount = 8626; addAmount = 390;}
         }
         //end married
         break;
      default:
         cout << "something went wrong" << endl;
         break;
   }
   double rate = 0;
   switch (taxRate){
      case 0: rate = 0.023; break;
      case 1: rate = 0.033; break;
      case 2: rate = 0.052; break;
      case 3: rate = 0.075; break;
   }
   double tax = (amount - subAmount) * rate + addAmount;
   tax = roundf(tax * 100) / 100;
   cout << tax << endl;
}

void calculateTax(){
   double taxableIncome = -1;
   // get the taxable income and make sure it is a positive amount. 
   while (taxableIncome < 0){
      cout << "Please enter in your taxable income.\n(This must be a positive value):" << endl;
      cin >> taxableIncome >> skipws;
   }
   char filingStatus = 'n';
   // get the filing status and make sure it is valid
   while(filingStatus != 'm' && filingStatus != 's'){
      cout << "Please enter m if married and filing joint return,\nor s if filing a single return:" << endl;
      cin >> filingStatus;
      cin.ignore(100, '\n');
   }
   cout << "Your taxable income is $" << taxableIncome << endl;
   // print out marital status
   switch(filingStatus){
      case 's':
         cout << "and you are filing a single return." << endl;
         break;
      case 'm':
         cout << "and you are filing a joint return." << endl;
         break;
      default: 
         cout << "something went wrong" << endl;
         break;
   }
   cout << "Your income tax will be $";
   CalculateTaxAmount(filingStatus, taxableIncome);
}

int main(){
   char rerun = 'a';
   do {
      calculateTax();
      while (rerun != 'q' && rerun != 'n' && rerun != 'y'){
         cout << "Would you like to do another calculation (y or n)?" << endl;
         cin >> rerun >> skipws;
      }
   }while (rerun == 'y');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have 2 loops with partly opposite conditions:

```
int main(){
   char rerun = 'a';
   do {
      calculateTax();
      while (rerun != 'q' && rerun != 'n' && rerun != 'y'){
         cout << "Would you like to do another calculation (y or n)?" << endl;
         cin >> rerun >> skipws;
      }
   }while (rerun == 'y');
}
```

pay your attention on

```
   do {
      while (/* ... && */ rerun != 'y'){
         //...
      }
   }while (rerun == 'y');
```

if inner loop finishes outer loop can not be finished and if outer loop can be completed - inner loop keeps handling...

So solution will be change one of this two conditions, you can choose your prefered way. I would suggest to remove `&& rerun != 'y'` from inner loop.

Comment: The inner loop is like that for a reason; to restrict input to one of 3 characters. The problem is that the rerun variable does not get reset after rerun has been done.

Answer (score 0):

It loops because when you enter 'y' rerun is set to 'y' and you have:

```
while (rerun == 'y');
```

rerun never changes after that.

Fixed code:

```
char rerun;
do {
  rerun = 'a';
  calculateTax();
  while (rerun != 'q' && rerun != 'n' && rerun != 'y'){
     cout << "Would you like to do another calculation (y or n)?" << endl;
      cin >> rerun >> skipws;
  }
} while (rerun == 'y');
```